# Remove everything that come before and including the last letter in an ID using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++, I am trying to figure out how to write a regular expression that removes  everything that comes before the last letter in a list of IDs. This includes the last letter the regular expression finds. Is this even possible?

Example:

```
Original list of IDs:
A1234AB985
A87654XY12578
R971E2MN8854
Y837E9BA1

Expected result:
985
12578
8854 
1
```

Comment: Replace [`^.*[A-Z]`](https://regex101.com/r/DYlNy4/1) with nothing.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I was trying something similar but I had ^.*=[A-Z]